# jstl Remove all whitespaces from a string

Tags: jstl

I am trying to remove all whitespaces from a jstl variable.

```
<c:set var="string1" value="This is first String         "/>
```

Trim only removes the trailing spaces but I want the output like:

> "ThisisfirstString "

with all spaces removed.Could anyone suggest?

Answer (score 10):

Okay I got the answer:

```
<c:set var="string1" value="This is first String."/>
<c:set var="string2" value="${fn:replace(string1,' ', '')}" />
```

Comment: there a better ways to do this, fn:trim being one of them.

Comment: trim does not work, as OP stated in the question, because it only removes whitespace from the front/back.

Comment: Please add this to your answer OP: <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>